# Python: The script extracts the mistakes: u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t'

Tags: python, scrapy

I am a beginner, this script works for me but mistakenly: 
Can anyone help me fix this code? This script does not extract numbers, why?

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class NameSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "name"
    allowed_domains = `["`example.com/`"]`
    start_urls = `[

        "http://www.example.com/"
            ]`
    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//td')
        for site in sites:

            extractcontent = site.select('text()').extract()
            print  extractcontent
```

This is what extract.

```
[u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t']
[u'  ', u' \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t Text']
[u'Text ']
[u'Text ']
[u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tText ']
[u' -  ']
[u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tText ']
[]
[u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t']
[u'  ', u' \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t Text']
[u'Text ']
[u'Text ']
[u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tText ']
[u' ', u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t ']
[u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tText ']
[]
[u'Text ']
[u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tText ']
[u' ', u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t ']
[u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tText ']
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: why should it extract numbers?

Comment: the site would be good to know. Are you sure there are numbers ? Maybe all there is are spaces, tabs and some text.

Comment: I don't think you want to be using backquotes like that.

Answer (score 0):

`.//text()` will get all text in the table cell `<td>` and `strip()` will remove the whitespace on either end of the results.

```
for site in sites:
    extractcontent = site.select('.//text()').extract()
    print  [c.strip() for c in extractcontent]
```

Comment: I implement your cod in my script but riceive error:

`def parse(self, response):
    ^
 IndentationError: unexpected indent`

`def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//td')
       for site in sites:
    extractcontent = site.select('.//text()').extract()
    print  [c.strip() for c in extractcontent]`
You can help me please? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: post your code so we can see it (not in comments), for example an update in your question or http://codepad.org/